# jquery not working when my laptop connected to internet at work

Tags: jquery, localhost, network-protocols, dreamweaver

My question is about jquery. Recently I have built a website as a project for a job. And one day the jquery stopped loading. It happened the day before I was fiddling with some jquery code, plus were trying to connect Dreamweaver CS6 with XAMPP thru local host. I am not sure whether it has something to do with it.

The issue with loading jquery is when I am at work and connected to the network by cable. In addition the www.jquery.com seems to be not loading css for my machine, it shows just a plain text and links. The people who are in the same office does have those issues. Moreover I cannot access `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"` from my browser.

The interesting thing is that when I connect my laptop to wireless at home, then everything works fine. And the website itself works fine on the remote server. So its only my office computer and laptop when connected to the local network. There was one article which was saying that it might something to do with 'host' file itself, but I checked, nothing different from default.

After researching the web, I have found a quick solution, rather then using `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`

I have tried `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js`  and it solved an issue of loading the website pages, but not the website *www.jquery.com* itself.

Anyway I am still looking for a solution, because I would have to make changes to present website. Moreover it is just interesting what it might be. But I cannot figure out what is the issue. Please help me, appreciate it.

Can it be explained why my browser does not show any jquery activity on this website: http://gvweb.es/add-ons/varios/zoomer/zoomer.html  where as I know that there is.

Any idea would be of great value, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot access src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" from your browser. Then copy all code from "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" & save the codes on a external .js file & call it on head section.

Comment: Hey, I have tried something similar. The way I have done is, I have downloaded the 1.3.2.js library and call it at the end of the body tag, just before declaration of path to effects.js file. Thank I will  try.

Comment: But still my web browser does not read the jquery.com website.

Comment: It did not work for me, but when I try other document, then it the right path is found ../../../../Desktop/Website/Library/jquery-1.3.2.js where as in other it simply gives as Library/jquery-1.3.2.js. And I still don't get any response of jquery from my browsers. They just don't load it, not my website on remote server, not jquery.com.

Comment: please look, is the java script enable or disable?

Comment: enable where? in a browser? on PC? Please more specific, because I am not so good with jquery. Thank you

Comment: Enable java script on your browser.

Comment: everything is enabled. I really think it is on the level of networking, cause when I use my laptop at home everything works fine even without google.ajax.api

Comment: hey, i have recently tried your option and it worked, only when I declare a path at the very top of the head tag. Although the same no response from jquery.com or http://gvweb.es/add-ons/varios/zoomer/zoomer.html Cannot find any solution, so just use what I have got.

Answer (score 0):

in case it is a case with every machine on your work network that no one is able to access *www.jquery.com* then your network administrator might have some policy which is restricting access to *www.jquery.com*

You can consult your network administrator on the same for a speedy resolution..

Comment: Apparently, it is only my pc,  laptop. Other people can access. Thank you

Comment: have you cleared your browsers' cache and in which browsers it is happening..?? second, sandeep pattanaik has suggested the other way that should work..

Comment: it is happening in every single that is installed on my pc. Does not matter whether I install new or use old one. Yes I have tried, the problem is that I cannot even access http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js, although I tried downloading the library itself, storing it in the Library folder of the root folder, but still whenever i call it nothing changes, as if I am cut off from jquery.com repository. Need to consult network administrator though.

Comment: when you are telling that other people can access..then imho consulting network administrator won't be of much use..you may consult a system administrator and get your laptop checked..saying this because it's a problem that is arising in a single machine and not for all nodes on the network..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot access that hosted copy of jQuery. This leaves you with a few options:

1. [Download](http://jquery.com/download/) your own copy of jQuery and host it with your application.
2. Use an alternative hosted copy of jQuery. [Google](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js) and [Microsoft](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js) also host copies of jQuery. You can learn more about them on the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/).

These solutions only work around the core issue, though. Since you indicate that only your laptop is impacted, this is likely a sign of a much more serious issue. When domains like that no longer resolve correctly, sometimes it's a sign of a virus, malware or other security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly I found a solution.

Apparently I had to override the configurations in the router or access point (dns serve configurations) in order to access and view action (jQuery, javascript) content of certain websites.

So I have followed an internet article: http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/how-to-bypass-open-dns/#comment-799

Brief instruction: Network and Sharing Center-Connections(Local area connection status)-Properties-Internet Protocol Versio 4(TCP/IPv4)-Propeties - General - Use the following DNS server address - Preferred DNS Server 8888 - Alternate DNS server - 8844

And it worked for me.

Thanks to all of you.